# excel vba: create filter for sheet2 with data taken from filter applied to sheet1

Tags: vba, excel, filter, filtering

So I'm pretty unfamiliar with excel and VBA but tried to dig into it the last couple of weeks. I need to set a filter for multiple sheets which contain in parts the same data (and columns). For filtering the same range in multiple sheets I have already found a simple solution:

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()

   Dim p As Integer, q As Integer

   p = Worksheets.Count

   For q = 1 To p
   With Worksheets(q)
   .AutoFilterMode = False
   .Range("A1").AutoFilter
   .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="2"
   End With
   Next q

End Sub
```

The real trouble starts here: I want to set a filter in sheet 1 to column 2, take the resulting data from column 1 and use it as a filter criteria for sheet 2 (and eventually 3). The sheets look something like this:

sheet1

```
| itemgroup | subject  | course
|         1 | biology  |  B.Sc.
|         1 | chemistry|  B.Sc.
|         1 | history  |  M.Sc.
|         2 | biology  |  B.Sc.
|         2 | history  |  B.Sc.
|         3 | chemistry|  B.Sc.
```

sheet2

```
| itemgroup | items 
|         1 | Example
|         1 | Example
|         2 | Example
|         3 | Example
```

For example I want to set as filter "biology" in sheet1 and then "1" and "2" should be set as filter for column 1 in sheet 2. 
I've used the code below. A filter is set to both worksheets, but worksheet 2 is only filtered by one criteria. The result looks like this:

[Sheet2 after Filter applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W0YW.jpg)

This is the data I apply the filter to: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6wLL0wGBKsNWHJ3bDYtdVd0cEE

The code I used:

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, filtValuesRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Itemgruppen") '<--| reference worksheet "Sheet1"
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<-- reference its data set
            .AutoFilter 2, "Biologie" '<--| filter it on column 2 with        criteria="biology"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then Set filtValuesRng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| if any value filtered then set them into a range
        End With
        '.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back and remove filters
    End With

    If filtValuesRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| if no values filtered from previous "Sheet1" column 2 filtering then exit

    With Worksheets("Itembloecke") '<--| reference worksheet "Sheet2"
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<-- reference its data set
            For Each cell In filtValuesRng '<--| iterate over "Sheet1" column filtered values
                .AutoFilter 1, cell.Value2 '<--| filter worksheet "Sheet2" dataset on column 1 with current "Sheet1" column filtered value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
'                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)... '<--| do something with filtered cells
                End If
            Next
        End With
        '.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back and remove filters
    End With
End Sub
```

This is my first question on  stack overflow - if you have any suggestions on how I could ask questions better I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' loop over all sheets
        sht.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove current filter

        sht.Range("A1").AutoFilter ' add new filter
        If sht.Name = "Sheet1" Then ' specifics for Sheet1
            sht.Range("A1").AutoFilter _ ' specify the options for the filter
                Field:=2, _ ' add criteria to second column
                    Criteria1:="biology"
        End If
        If sht.Name = "Sheet2" Then ' specifics for Sheet2
            sht.Range("A1").AutoFilter _ ' specify the options for the filter
                Field:=1, _ ' add criteria to first column
                    Criteria1:=Array("1", "2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues ' add multiple criterias
        End If

    Next sht


End Sub
```

Comment: it sets the filter in sheet1 but sets a totally different filter in sheet2.

Comment: @Robn thats what I thought you wanted? _For example I want to set as filter "biology" in sheet1 and then "1" and "2" should be set as filter for column 1 in sheet 2._

Comment: @Robn added comments to code... Also I just understood your issue now _The real trouble starts here: I want to set a filter in sheet 1 to column 2, take the resulting data from column 1 and use it as a filter criteria for sheet 2 (and eventually 3)._

Comment: sorry, my comment was misleading: the filter applied to sheet2 is different from the values in coulumn 1 sheet1 - the applied filter is "1" and "2" as set in the array.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, filtValuesRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| reference worksheet "Sheet1"
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<-- reference its data set
            .AutoFilter 2, "biology" '<--| filter it on column 2 with criteria="biology"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then Set filtValuesRng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| if any value filtered then set them into a range
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back and remove filters
    End With

    If filtValuesRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| if no values filtered from previous "Sheet1" column 2 filtering then exit

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") '<--| reference worksheet "Sheet2"
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<-- reference its data set
            For Each cell In filtValuesRng '<--| iterate over "Sheet1" column filtered values
                .AutoFilter 1, cell.Value2 '<--| filter worksheet "Sheet2" dataset on column 1 with current "Sheet1" column filtered value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
'                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)... '<--| do something with filtered cells
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back and remove filters
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for commenting the code! there's one problem: only the last entry in "itemgroup" (after filtering) is used as filter in sheet2 - with the example of the structure of my data: only "2" is set as Filter in sheet2 after I set "biology" as filter to sheet 1.

Comment: do "Sheet1" columns have headers? As per your example I assumed they had

Comment: I 'inserted' a table and the first row contains the headers for the columns (both in sheet1 and 2) - is that what you meant?

Comment: If by "table" you mean a "worksheet" then yes. I tested my code before answering and it correctly picks up both of the two _itemgroups_ corresponding to "biology " subject. Are you sure you don't get the proper behavior with those data? you may want to post the snapshot of data causing issues

Comment: I saw your comment in the "answer" (BTW: just remove it and update your question adding those links). So you have "real" `Tables`, while your question didn't mention them at all! Anyhow just try the code with your data in _plain_ worksheets cells (i.e. not wrapped inside a `Table`) and be sure not to have blank rows that would interrupt `CurrentRegion` method.

Comment: @Robn, did you get through it?

Comment: the filtered data is only shown if i comment out the 'AutoFilterMode = false' property (i wondered about that before, but it worked with the 'real' tables - could you tell me why you implemented that in the code?). but i still have the same problem: only the last entries in Range A1 of sheet1 are used as filter for sheet2 (so the result looks the same as in my picture).

Comment: @Robn, did you try it with data in "plain" worksheet cells (not in a Table)? Since I coded for and tested in such a scenario. Once you have it working there, then we could make some assumptions for the "Table" scenario

Comment: yes, the result was just the same as with the real Table.

Comment: Then we're not on the same page. Did you test lastly with data _exactly_ as per your question (with headers, no blank cells, sheet1 with those _exact_ 7 rows-3 columns and sheet2 with those _exact_ 5 rows-2 columns)?

Comment: Yeah, I did, unfortunately it's still the same problem... In sheet2 only "2" is set as filter.

Comment: So the last chance would be linking your worksheet (not a macro enabled one...)

Comment: I updated the question and uploaded the data. It would be great if you could take a look.